# Unmarshalling xml with nested schema

Tags: jaxb

I have a xml that contains an object with nested xsd. How should I annotate the inner class with that nested xsd?

I tried @XmlType annotation for the inner class but it is probably not the proper annotation.

Comment: Can you provide some additional informations? At least the current classes and the xsds you want to use.

Comment: Try: [XmlSeeAlso](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html)